# Target link that opened fancybox within beforeClose function?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a fancybox that gets opened via:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    fitToView : false,
    autoSize : false,
    height : 550,
    width : 650,
    beforeClose: function () {
        d = new Date();
        var imgObj = $('.fancybox').siblings('img');
        var imgSrc = imgObj.attr("src");
        imgObj.attr("src", imgSrc+"?"+d.getTime());
    }
});
```

As you can see in the `beforeClose` function I am trying to target a sibling image of the link that was clicked and reload the image by appending the time as a querystring.

The above code works, however it only works if there is 1 fancybox on the page. If there are more than 1 (which is what I'm wanting to do), then it reloads all the images on the page to the one next to the link that was clicked.

Is there a way I can target the link I clicked to open fancybox from within the `beforeClose` function?

I can't find anything on the fancybox documentation about how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this :

```
var imgObj = $('.fancybox').siblings('img');
```

... try this :

```
var imgObj = $(this.element).siblings('img');
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBQPm/)**